# Position 3 divs

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs, 'left div', 'right div' and 'bottom div'. I have been hopelessly trying to position them in a certain way but it just doesn't work. This is how I would ideally like them to be:
[image]

The main problem is the fact that 'left div' and 'right div' are of different heights so how would I sort this mess out?

EDIT: I would also like to add that the left and right divs need to be centered within the content area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="left">
        Left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Right
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        Bottom
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```css
#content{
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.left{
    width:495px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.right{
    width:495px;
    float:left;
}

.bottom{
    clear:both;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

then if you want the left and right to match:
(using jquery)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var leftdiv = $('.left').height();
    var rightdiv = $('.right').height();

    if(leftdiv > rightdiv)
        $('.right').css('height', leftdiv + 'px');
    else
        $('.left').css('height', rightdiv + 'px');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Statically set their heights or use javascript to match them if the height is dynamic based on content.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the HTML for the divs, remove the `#container` if you don't want to center them:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
    <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
#container {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    background: silver;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.bottom {
    clear: both;
    background: aqua;
}
```

I just used the colors to highlight the position. You can of course change the widths of the divs, but remember that the `#container` width has to be the width of `.left` + `.right`.

Read [this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/) to find out more about floats.
You can find a demo of the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/teaJb/

Answer (score 0):

float the left and right div's to their respective directions. set identical padding right and left on the containing div. on the bottom div apply "clear:both" to clear the float and "margin:0 auto" to center it relative to the container. 
if you don't match the heights, obviously the bottom div would appear after the higher div. you can match height using jquery's .height() method to compare the actual heights and set the higher value for both divs. Alternatively, you can just set a CSS rule for a constant height or a dynamic min-height.